# Find $f^{(100)}(x)$ where $f(x)=\frac{1}{4x^2-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Find $f^{(100)}(x)$ where $f(x)=\frac{1}{4x^2-1}$. I found first,second and third derivative:

$$f'(x)=\frac{-8x}{(4x^2-1)^2}$$

$$f''(x)=\frac{96x^2+8}{(4x^2-1)^3} $$

$$f'''(x)=\frac{-384x(4x^2+1)}{(4x^2-1)^4}$$

I can't seem to find any rule between them. Anyone has any ideas or hints?

Comment: **Hint:** you can find roots of denominator and then represent expression in form of partial fractions

Comment: I know what i want. And that is $f^{100}(x)$

Answer (score 4):

$$
f(x) =  \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2x-1} - \frac{1}{2x+1}\right)
$$
Now if $g(x) = \frac{1}{2x-1} = (2x-1)^{-1}$, then check (by induction) that
$$
g^{(n)}(x) = (-2)^nn!(2x-1)^{-(n+1)}
$$
and if $h(x)=(2x+1)^{-1}$, then
$$
h^{(n)}(x) = (-2)^nn!(2x+1)^{-(n+1)}
$$
Hence,
$$
f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-2)^nn!}{2} \left(\frac{1}{(2x-1)^{(n+1)}} - \frac{1}{(2x+1)^{(n+1)}}\right)
$$
Now take $n=100$.

Comment: Is it the Leibniz rule of successive differentiation?

Comment: Actually we can rewrite $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2x-1}-\frac{1}{2x+1}\right)\to\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}-x}+\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}-x}\right)$ and have no deal with powers of $(-2)$

Comment: Hehehehe... If you wanted to go in the direction, you could've pulled out the fractional derivative of $1/x$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom No, just inductively checked.  No need for anything too complicated, $n$th derivative of $1/x$ should be simple enough to guess at even.